# Can't I listen any kind of music by 7th percept?

Tags: precept, eight-precepts

```
Nacca gīta vādita visukadassanā
mālā gandha vilepana dhārana
mandana vibhūsanaṭṭhānā veramaṇi
sikkhāpadaṃ samādhiyāmi.
```

I undertake the precept to refrain from dancing, singing, music, going to [see entertainments](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/dn/dn.02.0.than_en.html#shows), [wearing garlands, using perfumes, and beautifying the body with cosmetics](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/dn/dn.02.0.than_en.html#scents)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- nacca - plays/dances
- gīta - song
- vādita - music
- visukadassanā - visiting shows

So yes, it includes all music. Even if you hear a song by chance and you indulge in it, you break the precept.

Comment: I think that another answer on this site (much earlier than this, I can't find it at the moment) suggests that if you're outside and happen to *hear* music that's not breaking the precept, so it's not necessary to actively avoid public places (e.g. a shop or elevator) might music might be heard. You shouldn't be *seeking* music or *going* to seek music (nor, as you said, perhaps *listening* to music instead of just *hearing* it).

Comment: The keyword is 'indulging'. It's like if a woman comes on to you and started having sex and you allow(indulge) it, you break the 3rd precept.

Answer (score 3):

Mr/mrs user73898

There are some people who say, even in the Commentary, that one would not break the precepts by listening to music which tells about the suffering in the world and causes *samvega*. But (if you are) being honest: isn't most music is not about lamenting (and so is certainly against the precept)? Stay with [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/13603/7555).

Actually it's about distracting the mind, so one would not stay at the Dhamma of staying mindful, and would even starts to ponder this and that; greed, hatred, all kinds of feeling can come up.

So if one takes it seriously one abstains form any kind of entertainment and diversion, including shows, films, sport games, games, parades ... and especially news and google and surfing :-) Everything that is not simply work.

*(Note: this answer has not been given with the agreement to be means of trade or the purpose of/for trade and/or keep people trapped and bound. How you handle it lies in your sphere, but does not excuse the deed here either.)*

Comment: `Actually it's about destructing the mind`? I trust you don't mind me asking, what was the "it" in this sentence ... are you saying that, "Actually *music* is about destructing the mind"? Or, "the *seventh precept* is about *not* destroying the mind"? It would be good to see one or more references to explain the intention or effect of the 7th precept.

Comment: Deflecting was meant, distracting, so a spell smell. Intention: Entertainment, nourishing, sustaining (uppadana) normal as clinging translated. Dico-light for the ears, or barbecue for the tongue, or special massage for the body, or riddles, questions and answers for the mind. Indulging in Sensual pleasure. And in the sense of tainting its also destruction of an possible clean mind.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @-}-- I asked because I'm so much addicted to listening music even I had planned to learn about sound engineering but I gave up because other reason.  I agree about 7th precept but you got really  what I want to ask. It is music could distrust mind really ?

Comment: Some traffic laws forbid listening to music while driving, or eating or cellphones. Yes, sensual pleasure disturbs the mind distracts the mind and one would be not really aware of what is going on, aside of indulging in an addiction. There are more people addicted to sound-pleasure then ever in this world. If one looks at them, they are really poor and have no freedom addicted to it and serve just illusion.

Comment: Love the disclaimer at the end, glad you found a work around to feel comfortable staying on the site and in the community

Comment: Thank you so much @-}-- As I'll practicing meditation that I'll got mind control and I'll abstain everything that could be cause of breaking eight precepts. Thank you so much for your valuable time. Thank you so much. @-}--

Comment: Doing it step by step but earnest is good. That means one needs to have patient with one self. Mudita with your resolve. Mr/mrs @hellyale , not really a disclaimer, as such is wrong view. Merely a reminder for everyone. How should Atma feel conformable being in the midst of wrong view?